# Grails Excel plugin how to import all sheets?

Tags: grails, apache-poi

The Excel-import plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import) is very easy to use, but when importing a file I have to specify the exact name of the sheet. But when I want to import many files i don't always know their names.
I didn't find any info on how to automatically import without specifying the exact name...

```
static Map CONFIG_BOOK_COLUMN_MAP = [
      sheet:'Sheet1', 
      startRow: 2,
      columnMap:  [
              'B':'title',
              'C':'author',
              'D':'numSold',
      ]
```

]

When i remove the "sheet" parameter unfortunately nothing gets imported...is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to iterate through the list of sheets to get the sheet names first, store those in an array then sequentially call your function to import the sheet in scope.